# How can I find out the rgb color of a C# backcolor

Tags: c#, winforms, styles

I want to know how can I find out the **RGB color code** or the **hex code** of the `BackColor of Scrollbar`.

Can someone please tell me how can I find this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I have searched around the internet and didn't find anything, That's why i asked this question. I need to know this because i need to change a image backcolor to match the color of my splashscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool that can 'read' the color where your mouse is. Ex. [Colorpix](http://www.colorschemer.com/colorpix_info.php)